# Facebook like button no show

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I have the following problem:
I would like to include a like button for a Facebook fan page at the corresponding web site. I tried to use the code from the developers page (xfbml and iframe), and plugins like https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing?frm=hp#.UONsR4k9sfk. For the iframe I tried different urls "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?...", "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?...", and "//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?..." without differing results.

A live example: [www.younglead.eu/examplepage](http://www.younglead.eu/examplepage) for the corresponding Facebook page: www.facebook.com/YoungEuropeanLeadership
The first like button appears always ('normal url'). For all the others (the facebook fan page): On my Computer (mac) the like button does not show on Chrome and Firefox but shows on Safari. I tried a different Mac OS, there it worked in Chrome but not Safari and Firefox. For Win OS it did not work for IE and Chrome.
Using other urls (Facebook and non-Facebook) also the other 4 like buttons show in all browsers (The the included second button for each example, where I added a "p" to the url).

The iframe code (for the //www... version):

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FYoungEuropeanLeadership&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21&amp;appId=322200017889372" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Do have an idea what I could do to overcome this weird situation? Your help is is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You have a number of HTML validation errors, you should fix these first as they are most probably causing your errors. Your example site seems to work fine for me (Mac OSX & Chrome), I can see all the facebook buttons (9 of them). Validation: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.younglead.eu%2Fexamplepage%2F

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to solve some of the problems and made a simplified page for this: [http://www.younglead.eu/examplepage2/](http://www.younglead.eu/examplepage2/). The validation errors concerning the widths and breadcrumbs are minor. I could not solve the errors "Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context." and "Bad value template for attribute name on element meta: Keyword template is not registered." as I have no web-coding experience.
Still, why would the content show different in on comparable browsers /machines?

Comment: I remember having similar issues with facebook a while ago, I believe I solved it by validating my html structure. The `element style...`error means you are using `<style>` in your body (it should be in your `<head>`. You have a number of facebook errors as well (duplicate id `#fb-root`), I think you should fix the facebook related errors and that may fix your issues.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply.
Unfortunately this did not do the trick: [Validator for http://www.younglead.eu/examplepage2/:](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.younglead.eu%2Fexamplepage2%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3)
Taking footer, header, and breadcrumbs out does not improve the situation either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
A previous administrator of the Facebook page had set country and age restrictions. Despite they included me at all the places I was this appeared to have caused the trouble.
fb.com/yourfanpage  > edit permissions

Thank you for the help anyways, I really appreciate it.